# node js как ограничить время выполнения команды в child_process?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я хочу запустить команду через child_process. Как ограничить процессорное время выполнения команды?

Нужно чтобы как только процессорное время выполнения программы превысило какое-то значение x, то процесс бы просто убивался

Comment: Простите, возможно, не всем ясно, что именно требуется. Если нужно, чтобы программа выполнялась не дольше определённого времени, может помочь опция timeout в методах запуска процессов. Если нужно понизить приоритет процесса, может помочь метод os.setPriority() (https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_setpriority_pid_priority)

Comment: Нужно чтобы как-только процессорное время выполнения программы превысило какое-то x, то процесс бы просто убивался

Answer (score 1):

Этой проблеме есть два решения. Простое и более сложное.

1. Проще всего будет использовать утилиту `timeout` из комплекта `coreutils`. Дописываете её к запускаемой команде, и готово:

   ```
   timeout -k 60 30 my_command
   ```

   С этими аргументами команду вежливо попросят на выход через 30 секунд и прибьют напрочь через 60 секунд.

   Процессорное время в первом приближении можно получить поделив реальное время на число потоков, с которым выполняется ваша программа. Если ваша программа не имеет фиксированного числа потоков, то можно делить на число ядер процессора, которое подскажет команда `nproc`.
2. Более сложным решением будет вызывать системную функцию `getrusage` в цикле с небольшим перерывом. [Есть одноимённый пакет.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/getrusage) В этом случае вам нужно будет самим делать всю работу, что за вас делает команда `timeout`, получая сомнительную выгоду в точности использованных ресурсов в обмен на значительное усложнение самой программы и тестов.

Comment: так он вроде ограничивает реальное время, а не процессорное. Если сделать time sleep 100 то sys будет равен 0. Но timeout убьет его раньше

Comment: Верно, но если вы знаете что ваша программа выполняется в N потоков, поделите реальное время на N и получите процессорное в первом приближении.

Comment: мне нужно точное значение